# How can I tell which function of two variables is larger?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

[image: Example Problem Image]

In this case, $z = 1$ and $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. How can I tell which function is bigger to choose the upper and lower bound?

Comment: If you take $1 \leq z \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, there will be no upper limit for $x$ and $y$. Then you should take $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq 1$ for solid to be finite. One doesn't need calculus to solve this problem.

Comment: If you sketch or visualize the surfaces, you can see there's only one bounded region surrounded by them, and you know which has larger $z$ values around that region. Do you need help with what they look like?

Comment: You can try to draw the surfaces. if you don't know how - you can set any point inside the area in the equations (although not always works , you should be careful with this approach). set $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and you get that the height of the cone at that point is $z=0$ , yet the plane $z=1$ is $1$ at any point. so you notice the cone is bounded below the plane so it's $z$ values are smaller.